# How to read a named pipe on Windows?

Tags: streams

Tried to open an Out named pipe from Powershell

```
$pipe = new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream 'testpipe','Out'
$pipe.WaitForConnection()
$sw = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter $pipe
$sw.AutoFlush = $true
$sw.WriteLine("Server pid is $pid")
$sw.Dispose()
$pipe.Dispose()
```

and use `Get` to read the named pipe.

```
Get["\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe"]
```

The following messages were shown in Powershell and Mathematica

```
Exception calling "WriteLine" with "1" argument(s): "Pipe is broken."
At line:5 char:1
+ $sw.WriteLine("Server pid is $pid")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException

Exception calling "Dispose" with "0" argument(s): "Pipe is broken."
At line:6 char:1
+ $sw.Dispose()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException
```

```
Get::noopen: Cannot open \\.\pipe\testpipe.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short Version**

On Windows, unlike Unix, named pipes are special and do not behave like regular *stdio* streams.  Programs that use named pipes require custom logic.  As a rule the Wolfram Language I/O functions, like most *stdio* programs, do not have that custom logic.

**Details**

Reading from a named pipe on Windows is a tricky business.  There are all kinds of race conditions that can cause a pipe endpoint to be temporarily busy.  In this case, the server is ever-so-briefly busy as it spins up its *StreamWriter* so it returns a *ERROR_PIPE_BUSY* error to the client.  The client aborts and closes the pipe.  When the server gets around to writing some bytes to the pipe, if finds that the *Pipe is broken*.

On Windows, named pipe client code is required to expect *ERROR_PIPE_BUSY* and to poll or call [WaitNamedPipe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winbase/nf-winbase-waitnamedpipea) in response.  Unfortunately, the WL I/O functions, like 99% of *stdio* programs in the wild, do not have this custom logic.  Indeed, even the Windows command line tools lack it:

```vb
C:\> type \\.\pipe\testpipe

All pipe instances are busy.
```

**NETLINK Work-around**

One way to work around this problem is to use the [NamedPipeClientStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream?view=netframework-4.8) class directly through `NETLink`:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[];
LoadNETType["System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection"];
```

Then, with the PowerShell server running, evaluate:

```
NETBlock @
  Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    {pipe = NETNew["System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream", ".", "testPipe", PipeDirection`In]}
  , pipe@Connect[]
  ; Internal`WithLocalSettings[
      {stream = NETNew["System.IO.StreamReader", pipe]}
    , stream@ReadLine[]
    , stream@Dispose[]
    ]
  , pipe@Dispose[]
  ]

(* "Server pid is 12345" *)
```

Comment: Hi @WReach, thanks for your amazing response. I am using MMA 11.3, but it always needs to `LoadNETType` twice to get the correct type. It will first throw the message that `NET::netexcptn: A .NET exception occurred: System.TypeLoadException: Type System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection not found.
   at Wolfram.NETLink.TypeLoader.GetType(String typeName, String assemblyName, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Wolfram.NETLink.Internal.CallPacketHandler.loadType1(KernelLinkImpl ml).` And everything goes fine when I execute it again. Do you know the reason?

Comment: That is strange.  I tried it with 11.3 as well and I did not get the _TypeLoadException_.  Perhaps try calling `InstallNET[]` explicitly prior to `LoadNETType[...]`.